# How to prevent constructor of an parent class being called while using child class in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, es6-class

If I have two classes in javascript one inheriting other.
When the constructor of base class runs, the constructor of parent class is also called.

```js
    class Parent{
        constructor(){
            alert("Parent constructor Called");
        }
    }

    var parent = new Parent();
    
    class Child extends Parent{
        constructor(){
            super();
            alert("Child constructor Called");
        }
    }
   
    var child = new Child();
```

Results:-

```
var parent = new Parent();
```

Output ->

1. Alert is made -> "Parent constructor Called".

   var child = new Child();

Output ->

1. Alert is made -> "Parent constructor Called"
2. Alert is made -> "Child constructor Called"

How do I prevent the constructor of parent class being called when making object of child class.
I am facing a problem that, the parent constructor is calling `events` method of parent class which calls a method with some ajax request inside it.
I want to use the same ajax calling method in the base class too, and I call the that method in `events` method of child class, and that `events` method calls the method containing ajax request, but since parent the constructor calls those methods for where it is needed, the ajax method is called twice fetching the same data again.
Also many variable names in both the classes are same.

Comment: You can spare calling `super()` in your constructor. That will prevent calling the parent constructor.

Comment: "*the constructor is calling events method of the class which calls a method with some ajax request inside it*" - there's your actual problem, don't do that. A constructor should only initialise the instance, it should never trigger any side effects such as an ajax request.

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann No, you can't do that. It will throw an exception if you don't call  `super()` in an inheriting class.

Comment: @Bergi totally right! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Sam If you could [edit] your question to include your actual code, I could give some concrete suggestions

Answer (score -2):

By design, every inherited class will always first run the parent constructor.

What you need is to change your implementation so that you can override the behavior.

```js
class Parent{
      alert() {
          alert("Parent constructor Called");
      }

      constructor() {
          this.alert();        
      }
  }

  var parent = new Parent();

  class Child extends Parent{
      alert() {
          alert("Child constructor Called");
      }    
  }

  var child = new Child();
```

Comment: No. Calling an overridable method from the constructor is an absolutely bad practice.